# cannot list parameters for pytorch network

Tags: python, optimization, pytorch

I am trying to build a nest unet with the following structure:

```py
class EFUnet(nn.Module):

    backbone = efn.EfficientNetB3(
        weights=None,
        include_top=False,
        input_shape=(256,1600,3)
    )

    backbone.load_weights(('../input/efficientnet-keras-weights-b0b5/'
                           'efficientnet-b3_imagenet_1000_notop.h5'))

    def __init(self,in_channel = 3, out_channels = 1, features = 32):
        super(EFUnet, self).__init__()

        self.conv00 = backbone.input  
        self.conv10 = backbone.get_layer('stem_activation').output  
        self.conv20 = backbone.get_layer('block2c_add').output 
        self.conv30 = backbone.get_layer('block3c_add').output  
        self.conv40 = backbone.get_layer('block5e_add').output  
        self.conv50 = backbone.get_layer('block7b_add').output

        self.conv01 = _H(features*(2^0+2^1), features*2^0)
        self.conv11 = _H(feathres*(2^1+2^2),feature*2^1)
        self.conv21 = _H(feathres*(2^2+2^3),feature*2^2)
        self.conv31 = _H(feathres*(2^3+2^4),feature*2^3)
        self.conv41 = _H(feathres*(2^4+2^5),feature*2^4)

        self.conv02 = _H(features*(2^0*2+2^1), features*2^0)
        self.conv12 = _H(features*(2^1*2+2^2), features*2^1)
        self.conv22 = _H(features*(2^2*2+2^3), features*2^2)
        self.conv32 = _H(features*(2^3*2+2^4), features*2^3)

        self.conv03 = _H(features*(2^0*3+2^1), features*2^0)
        self.conv13 = _H(features*(2^1*3+2^2), features*2^1)
        self.conv23 = _H(features*(2^2*3+2^3), features*2^2)

        self.conv04 = _H(features*(2^0*4+2^1), features*2^0)
        self.conv14 = _H(features*(2^1*4+2^2), features*2^1)

        self.conv05 = _H(features*(2^0*5+2^1), features*2^0)

        self.final1 = nn.Conv2d(features, 1, kernel_size=1)
        self.final2 = nn.Conv2d(features, 1, kernel_size=1)
        self.final3 = nn.Conv2d(features, 1, kernel_size=1)
        self.final4 = nn.Conv2d(features, 1, kernel_size=1)
        self.final5 = nn.Conv2d(features, 1, kernel_size=1)

        self.final = nn.Conv2d(feature*5, 4, (3,3), padding="same", activation="sigmoid")

    def forward(self,input):

        x00 = self.conv00(input)

        x10 = self.conv10(x00)
        x01 = self.conv01(torch.cat([x00,self._U(x10)],1))

        x20 = self.conv20(x10)
        x11 = self.conv11(torch.cat([x10,self._U(x20)],1))
        x02 = self.conv02(torch.cat([x00,x01,self._U(x11)],1))

        x30 = self.conv30(x20)
        x21 = self.conv21(torch.cat([x20,self._U(x30)],1))
        x12 = self.conv12(torch.cat([x10,x11,self._U(x21)],1))
        x03 = self.conv03(torch.cat([x00,x01,x02,self._U(x12)],1))

        x40 = self.conv40(x30)
        x31 = self.conv31(torch.cat([x30,self._U(x40)],1))
        x22 = self.conv22(torch.cat([x20,x21,self._U(x31)],1))
        x13 = self.conv13(torch.cat([x10,x11,x12,self._U(x22)],1))
        x04 = self.conv04(torch.cat([x00,x01,x02,x03,self._U(x13)],1))

        x50 = self.conv50(x40)
        x41 = self.conv41(torch.cat([x40,self._U(x50)],1))
        x32 = self.conv32(torch.cat([x30,x31,self._U(x41)],1))
        x23 = self.conv23(torch.cat([x20,x21,x22,self._U(x32)],1))
        x14 = self.conv14(torch.cat([x10,x11,x12,x13,self._U(x23)],1))
        x05 = self.conv05(torch.cat([x00,x01,x02,x03,x04,self._U(x14)],1))  

        output1 = self.final1(x01)
        output2 = self.final2(x02)
        output3 = self.final3(x03)
        output4 = self.final4(x04)
        output5 = self.final4(x05)

        x_out = torch.cat([output1, output2, output3, output4, output5],1)
        x_out = self.final(x_out)

        return x_out

    def _H(in_channels, features, use_gn=True):
        if use_gn:
            norm = torch.nn.GroupNorm(num_channels = 3, num_groups=1)
        else:
            norm = BatchNormalization(number_features = features)

        return nn.Sequential(
            OrderedDict(
                [
                    (name + "conv", nn.Conv2D(in_channels, features, (2, 2), padding='same')),
                    (name + "norm", norm()),
                    (name + 'LReLU',LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))
                ]
            )
        )

    def _U(in_channels, features, use_gn=True):
        if use_gn:
            norm = torch.nn.GroupNorm(num_channels = 3, num_groups=1)
        else:
            norm = BatchNormalization(number_features = features)

        return nn.Sequential(
            OrderedDict(
                [
                    (name + "upconv", nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels, features, (2, 2), padding='same')),
                    (name + "norm", norm()),
                    (name + 'LReLU',LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))
                ]
            )
        )
```

When I put it in the adam optimizer. It complaint that 
`ValueError: optimizer got an empty parameter list`

So i try to do some QC to check the parameters of the Unet. with the following code:

```py
model = EFUnet()
model = model.cuda()
print(list(model.parameters))
```

However, python complaint that the output is a method which is not iterable.

`TypeError: 'method' object is not iterable`

Can any one help to see what is causing the issue that python not get the parameters?

Thank you!

Comment: `model.parameters` is a *method* that returns the parameters, its not the parameters themselves. try `model.parameters()` instead.

Comment: Thanks. I think it fixed the issue. But the output of model.parameters() turned out to be an empty list. Also, I put this network in the optimizer `optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=self.lr)`,  It complaint that model parameter list is empty: `ValueError: optimizer got an empty parameter list`. Any ideal what is wrong with my settings? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In pytorch to get the parameters, one should call the method `model.parameters()` which will return a generator object on which you can iterate.

or

A better approach will be to use `model.named_parameters()` which will again return a generator object were parameters are mapped with the corresponding layer name.

Answer (score 0):

Instead:

```
print(list(model.parameters))
```

use:

```
print(list(model.parameters()))
```

or

```
print(list(model.named_parameters())
```

or

```
for p in model.named_parameters():
    print(p[0],":",p[1].size() )
```